# React Native - recursive setTimeout to repeatedly run something

Tags: react-native, settimeout

The code below is just a mock up of a screen that appears when there's an error in loading data (specifically temporary network loss). What I'm trying to do is on mount run the 'refresh' function and keep running it every 10 seconds until the variable 'online' changes from 'false' to 'true'. Here I change it with a button, in the real screen it'll be an async call to load data (if data loaded, it'll become true). So the idea is to keep trying to load data.

What happens in the code below is it console logs 'still offline' every 10 seconds but then when I press the button, it correctly logs 'back on line' but then it goes back to logging 'still offline' every 10 seconds. It should clear the timeout and in reality the screen will be unmounted.

```
 const [online, setOnline] = useState(false);
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);
      
  const handleChange = () => {
    setOnline(!online);
  };

  const refresh = useCallback(async () => {
    setLoading(true);
    
    // in the real screen the following will be assigned to 'online'
    // const online = await loadData()
   
    if (!online) {
      setLoading(true);
      setTimeout(refresh, 10000);
      console.log('still offline');
    } else {
      setLoading(false);
      clearTimeout(refresh);
      console.log('back on line');
    }
  }, [online]);

  useEffect(() => {
    setTimeout(refresh, 10000);
  }, [online, refresh]);

  return (
    <View>
      {online ? <Text>Online</Text> : <Text>Offline</Text>}
      {loading ? <Text>Loading</Text> : <Text>IDLE</Text>}
      <Button title="Go Online" onPress={handleChange} />
    </View>
  );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you wanna cancel a previously setup timer you need to store the timer id returned by `setTimeout`, you must not pass the setTimeout callback function itself.

```
const myTimerID = setTimeout(refresh, 10000);
...
clearTimeout(myTimerID)
```

Take a look at my [sample](https://snack.expo.dev/@m.bahl/settimeout-handling)

Comment: Thanks but after loggin 'back online', it keeps logging 'still offline'. I'm starting to suspect it might be to do with useCallback but it doesn't let me remove it. ESlint/Prettier puts it back on. Also, it doesn't like using 'this' in functional components

Comment: Sorry for my fault, my sample was only working for web.
I updated my sample, please check and let me know if it's working now.

Comment: Thanks. This one works fine. The getOnlineState function is not necessary. Works without that. Is there any way of getting rid of 'this'? It does not pass the ESLint checks if I wanted to commit this. Thank you

Comment: Sure as it is functional component, better use useRef as ESLint suggests. 
Amend my sample once more.

Comment: Great. Why haven't I thought of useRef?!